# Login located in iFrame not reloading page using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, browser-automation

I'm trying to create a script to log into my account. I have gotten to the point where I can enter the username and such in, but whether I submit, send enter, or click the login button, the iFrame box goes blank, yet the page doesn't reload to the logged in page.

I've noticed that regardless of the number of sleeps I put in, the result doesn't change. However, if I manually press enter or click the submit button, the page will reload properly.

Any solutions?

Edit: http://mpe.berklee.edu/studio/booking/practice.php

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginframe"]'))
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
loginButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="submitit"]')

login.send_keys('XXXXXX')
password.send_keys('XXXXXX')
time.sleep(1)
password.submit()
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: May be the button you are clicking is not correct? Can you share the url/html source where you are trying to login?

Comment: For now if you try `passoword.send_keys('XXXX\n')`, then it tries to login, but why `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('form').submit()` is failing, I don't know yet.

Comment: That works, thank you so much. It does seem odd that the other approaches don't work though...