# How do I click on a table value using Selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, html-table, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select a cell in the table, but it doesn't seem to recognize the cell as a clickable object (at least by the way that I am finding the element). I've tried switching up how I refer to the element, but that has yielded the same thing. I'm not sure how else I can select the cell besides clicking it.

My code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_reference=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="practice_schedule"]'))
#checkBox = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#emsscheduletab > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > th')
timeBox1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="18-22"]')
timeBox2 = ''
timeBox1.click()
```

The error:
[image: PythonErrorMessage]

The HTML:
[image: HTMLScreenCap]

Thoughts?

Comment: Try to [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) until element with class name `"wscrBannerContent"` is not visible

Comment: I strongly believe this question is the outcome of jumping into the conclusion too early with your two previous questions [How to switch to iFrame, not working in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627122/how-to-switch-to-iframe-not-working-in-selenium) and [Login located in iFrame not reloading page using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625732/login-located-in-iframe-not-reloading-page-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must wait for the element to load and be clickable on the screen.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")));

element.click();
```